# How run a for loop on 5 month?

Tags: date, array, for

I created this loop that activate my script only on 1 month (20170301 - 20170331):

`for ((i = 20170301; i<=20170331; i++)) ; do /home/jul/exp/prod/client/apps/scripts/runCer client-layer-name $i; done`

but I want it to run on 5 month (between 20170301 -20170831), how can I do that ?

Comment: Maybe you could overwrite the `20170331` to `20170831`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming GNU `date` is available, you can use this `bash`/`ksh93`/`zsh` script:

```
start=$(date -ud 20170301 "+%s") # start time in epoch time (seconds since Jan. 1st, 1970)
end=$(date -ud 20170831 "+%s") # end time 

for ((i=start; i <= end; i+=86400)); do # 86400 is 24 hours
    runCerclient-layer-name "$(date -ud "@$i" +%Y%m%d)"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This loop runs for 5*30 days, starting at 20170301:

```
for (( i=0; i <= 150; ++i )); do
    thedate=$( date -d "20170301 + $i days" "+%Y%m%d" )
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$thedate"
done
```

This doesn't take us all the way to 20170831 though, so...

This one runs from one date until we hit a particular end date:

```
startdate='20170301'
thedate=$startdate

for (( i=0; thedate != 20170831; ++i )); do
    thedate=$( date -d "$startdate + $i days" "+%Y%m%d" )
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$thedate"
done
```

This uses a start date and calculates the end date 5 months into the future from that date, then loops there:

```
startdate='20170301'
enddate=$( date -d "$startdate + 5 months" "+%Y%m%d" )

thedate=$startdate

for (( i=0; thedate != enddate; ++i )); do
    thedate=$( date -d "$startdate + $i days" "+%Y%m%d" )
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$thedate"
done
```

This assumes GNU `date` and a shell like `bash`, `ksh93`, or `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `dateseq` (sometimes called `dseq` or `dateutils.dseq`) from `dateutils` for that:

```
dateseq -{i,f}%Y%m%d 20170301 20170831
```

Of the 3 shells that support that `for ((...))` syntax (`ksh93` (where it comes from), `zsh` and `bash`) two have built-in support for that, though in different ways:

### ksh93

```
for ((i = 20170301; i<=20170831; i=$(TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' "$i 24:00")))
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

### zsh

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
for ((i = 20170301; i<=20170831;)); do
  echo "$i"
  TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs s %Y%m%d $i
  TZ=UTC0 strftime  -s i %Y%m%d $((s + 86400))
done
```

### bash

The GNU shell's `printf` also supports `ksh93`-like `%T` but only for formatting, not for parsing dates. However, where `bash` is available, GNU `date` is often available and several answers have been given for that.

Other `date` implementations like busybox's or BSDs also have the capability but with different syntax.

Other alternatives include GNU `awk` or `perl`.